# redirect to specific div when img click

Tags: html, css

im trying to redirect to a specific location from the page when i click an image with link, the image has a link redirection.

sample img1 link www.test.com/#contactUs

```
<div id="home">
</div>

<div id="aboutUs">
</div>

<div id="contactUs">
</div>
```

what i wanted to do is when i click the img it will redirect to the contactUs div but the problem is when i tried to access access the page and clicks the link it redirects exactly to the contactUs tab but when i tried to use other device i encountered the img link redirects at the middle of aboutUs tab and constactUs tab or above contactUs div it doesn't redirects to the contactUs tab exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following code on onclick of image:

`elmnt = document.getElementById("contactUs");
 elmnt.scrollTop = 0`

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: i tried it and it didn't go to contactUs, it goes above it.. i need to scroll it down to go to contactUs tab

Comment: Try adjusting that scrolltop value then